# Convert string to function with parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with writing a regular expression to turn the string

```
"fetchSomething('param1','param2','param3')"
```

into the proper function call. I can do it with some splitting and substrings but would rather do it with a `.match` using capture groups for efficiency's sake (and my own education).

However when I use

```
'something("stuff","moreStuff","yetMoreStuff")'.match(/(?:\(|,)("?\w+"?)/g)
```

I get

```
["("stuff"", ","moreStuff"", ","yetMoreStuff""]
```

Which is the same result regardless of the `?:`, this confuses me since I thought `?:` would cause it to ignore the first capture group? Or am I completely miss understanding capture groups?

Comment: I'd recommend to use an actual JS syntax parser, such as http://esprima.org/. Or, depending on the source of the input and the overall context, what about `eval`?

Comment: FWIW, if you use `.match` with the `g` modifier, the array only returns the whole matches, not capture groups. You might want to have a look at [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: I'm limited by the libraries we already have unfortunately. We're using extJS. I'm also viewing this as an exercise in understanding regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to look at exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the whole string when you have the `g` flag active. If you're going only after the sub-matches, then you will need to use `.exec` and a loop:

```
var regex = /(?:\(|,)("?\w+"?)/g;
var s = 'something("stuff","moreStuff","yetMoreStuff")';
var match, matches=[];

while ( (match=regex.exec(s)) !== null ) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

alert(matches);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XLN7/)

Comment: This will fail on `"fetchSomething('param1','param2','param3')"`, which was the very first example in the question. This will fail if any of the parameters in the expression to be parsed contain an escaped double quote, or a comma, or an open parenthesis. Felix King was right on the money in his comment on the question.

Comment: @Louis I was actually expecting the OP to be telling something like that and change the regex accordingly, but they didn't. If _you_ want to get a regex that breaks less easily according to the issues you pointed out, you could use something like [that](http://regex101.com/r/cX6gP8). OP's goal is to get more practise, and they have limited libraries. Should their question be ignored because of that?